# Aggregate/Remove duplicate rows in DataFrame based on swapped index levels

Tags: pandas

### Sample input

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['A', 'B', 1, 5],
        ['B', 'C', 2, 2],
        ['B', 'A', 1, 1],
        ['C', 'B', 1, 3]], 
        columns=['from', 'to', 'type', 'value']) 
df = df.set_index(['from', 'to', 'type'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
                  value
from  to    type    
A     B     1     5
B     C     2     2
      A     1     1
C     B     1     3
```

### Goal

I now want to remove "duplicate" rows from this in the following sense: for each row with an arbitrary index `(from, to, type)`, if there exists a row `(to, from, type)`, the value of the *second* row should be **added** to the *first* row **and the second row be dropped**. In the example above, the row `(B, A, 1)` with value `1` should be added to the first row and dropped, leading to the following desired result.

### Sample result

```
                  value
from  to  type
A     B   1       6
B     C   2       2
C     B   1       3
```

This is my best try so far. It feels unnecessarily verbose and clunky:

```
# aggregate val of rows with (from,to,type) == (to,from,type) 
df2 = df.reset_index()
df3 = df2.rename(columns={'from':'to', 'to':'from'})
df_both = df.join(df3.set_index(
                    ['from', 'to', 'type']), 
                    rsuffix='_b').sum(axis=1)

# then remove the second, i.e. the (to,from,t) row
rows_to_keep = []
rows_to_remove = []
for a,b,t in df_both.index:
    if (b,a,t) in df_both.index and not (b,a,t) in rows_to_keep:
        rows_to_keep.append((a,b,t))
        rows_to_remove.append((b,a,t))

df_final = df_both.drop(rows_to_remove)
df_final
```

Especially the second "de-duplication" step feels very unpythonic. (How) can I improve these steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much better this is, but it's certainly different

```
  import pandas as pd
  from collections import Counter

  df = pd.DataFrame([
          ['A', 'B', 1, 5],
          ['B', 'C', 2, 2],
          ['B', 'A', 1, 1],
          ['C', 'B', 1, 3]], 
          columns=['from', 'to', 'type', 'value']) 
  df = df.set_index(['from', 'to', 'type'])
  ls = df.to_records()
  ls = list(ls)
  ls2=[]
  for l in ls:
      i=0
      while i <= l[3]:
          ls2.append(list(l)[:3])
          i+=1
  counted = Counter(tuple(sorted(entry)) for entry in ls2)
```